# Problem with GitHub Pages Jekyll Template

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme, github-pages-deploy-action

I have a problem with GitHub Pages personal site, which I want to create from this template:
[**portfolYOU** by YoussefRaafatNasry](https://github.com/YoussefRaafatNasry/portfolYOU)

I was able to figure out how to test the site locally with Jekyll and everything worked great. After I tried to upload the project to GitHub.

At first I forgot to edit the `_config.yml` file, the site worked on the main link, but transitions to all pages and all interactive elements worked with an error.

After editing the `_config.yml` file, loading the site on GitHub became impossible - I observe an error in GitHub Actions (GitHub use it by itself), the cause of which I cannot determine.

> Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
> /usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioactionsjekyllbuildpagesv104_23b786 --label ea425b --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_DESTINATION" -e "INPUT_FUTURE" -e "INPUT_BUILD_REVISION" -e "INPUT_VERBOSE" -e "INPUT_TOKEN" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/evklo.github.io/evklo.github.io":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.4
> Logging at level: debug
> Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml
> GitHub Pages: github-pages v227
> GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.2
> Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
> Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
> Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
> To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
> ****Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'elements/highlight.html' in any of ["/github/workspace/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and is not a symlink as those are not allowed in safe mode. in /github/workspace/_posts/2018-12-01-what-the-heck-is-a-callback.md****
> /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:121:in `locate_include_file': Could not locate the included file 'elements/highlight.html' in any of ["/github/workspace/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and is not a symlink as those are not allowed in safe mode. (IOError) from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:130:in` render'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:91:in` render'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:208:in `block in render' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:242:in` with_profiling'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:207:in `render' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:220:in` render!'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in render!' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:42:in` measure_bytes'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:29:in `block in render!' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:49:in` measure_time'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:28:in `render!' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:126:in` render_liquid'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:79:in `render_document' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:62:in` run'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:479:in `render_regenerated' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:464:in` block (2 levels) in render_docs'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:463:in `each' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:463:in` block in render_docs'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:462:in `each_value' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:462:in` render_docs'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:191:in `render' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:71:in` process'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in` build'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-227/bin/github-pages:70:in` block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in` each'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in` go'
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-227/bin/github-pages:6:in` <top (required)>'
> from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in` '
> Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag
> Requiring: jemoji
> Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript
> Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages
> Requiring: jekyll-gist
> Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
> Requiring: jekyll-paginate
> Requiring: jekyll-relative-links
> Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter
> Requiring: jekyll-readme-index
> Requiring: jekyll-default-layout
> Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings
> Requiring: jekyll-remote-theme
> GitHub Metadata: Initializing...
> Source: /github/workspace/.
> Destination: /github/workspace/./_site
> Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
> Generating...
> Theme: evklo/evklo.github.io
> Theme source: /tmp/jekyll-remote-theme-20230123-7-1e2b06p
> Remote Theme: Using theme evklo/evklo.github.io
> Remote Theme: Downloading https://codeload.github.com/evklo/evklo.github.io/zip/HEAD to /tmp/jekyll-remote-theme-20230123-7-zbex2n.zip
> Remote Theme: Unzipping /tmp/jekyll-remote-theme-20230123-7-zbex2n.zip to /tmp/jekyll-remote-theme-20230123-7-1e2b06p
> Reading: _posts/2016-07-23-a-better-hello-world.md
> Reading: _posts/2016-02-09-what-is-version-control.md
> Reading: _posts/2019-02-15-learn-react-js.md
> Reading: _posts/2018-12-01-what-the-heck-is-a-callback.md
> Reading: _posts/2015-09-25-how-to-undo-your-git-failure.md
> Reading: _posts/2019-02-20-digital-minimalism.md
> Reading: _posts/2018-12-10-clean-coding.md
> Reading: _posts/2018-05-09-four-lessons-after-eleven-years-in-silicon-valley.md
> Reading: _posts/2016-04-17-do-not-go-gentle-into-that-good-night.md
> Reading: _posts/2017-01-01-github-flow.md
> Reading: _projects/(2) Awesome Project.md
> Reading: _projects/(6) Dummy Project.md
> Reading: _projects/(1) PlaceHolder Project.md
> Reading: _projects/(4) VVG on GitHub.md
> Reading: _projects/(5) The Fabulous.md
> Reading: _projects/(3) Empty Project.md
> Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 4.24e-05 seconds.
> Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 5.13e-05 seconds.
> Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 8.5e-06 seconds.
> Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 4.8201e-05 seconds.
> Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 0.002420515 seconds.
> Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 5.65e-05 seconds.
> Rendering: _posts/2015-09-25-how-to-undo-your-git-failure.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2015-09-25-how-to-undo-your-git-failure.md
> Rendering Markup: _posts/2015-09-25-how-to-undo-your-git-failure.md
> Requiring: kramdown-parser-gfm
> Rendering Layout: _posts/2015-09-25-how-to-undo-your-git-failure.md
> Rendering: _posts/2016-02-09-what-is-version-control.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2016-02-09-what-is-version-control.md
> Rendering Markup: _posts/2016-02-09-what-is-version-control.md
> Rendering Layout: _posts/2016-02-09-what-is-version-control.md
> Rendering: _posts/2016-04-17-do-not-go-gentle-into-that-good-night.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2016-04-17-do-not-go-gentle-into-that-good-night.md
> Rendering Markup: _posts/2016-04-17-do-not-go-gentle-into-that-good-night.md
> Rendering Layout: _posts/2016-04-17-do-not-go-gentle-into-that-good-night.md
> Rendering: _posts/2016-07-23-a-better-hello-world.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2016-07-23-a-better-hello-world.md
> Rendering Markup: _posts/2016-07-23-a-better-hello-world.md
> Rendering Layout: _posts/2016-07-23-a-better-hello-world.md
> Rendering: _posts/2017-01-01-github-flow.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2017-01-01-github-flow.md
> Rendering Markup: _posts/2017-01-01-github-flow.md
> Rendering Layout: _posts/2017-01-01-github-flow.md
> Rendering: _posts/2018-05-09-four-lessons-after-eleven-years-in-silicon-valley.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2018-05-09-four-lessons-after-eleven-years-in-silicon-valley.md
> Rendering Markup: _posts/2018-05-09-four-lessons-after-eleven-years-in-silicon-valley.md
> Rendering Layout: _posts/2018-05-09-four-lessons-after-eleven-years-in-silicon-valley.md
> Rendering: _posts/2018-12-01-what-the-heck-is-a-callback.md
> Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2018-12-01-what-the-heck-is-a-callback.md
> Rendering Liquid: _posts/2018-12-01-what-the-heck-is-a-callback.md
> github-pages 227 | Error:  Could not locate the included file 'elements/highlight.html' in any of ["/github/workspace/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and is not a symlink as those are not allowed in safe mode.
> Remote Theme: Cleaning up /tmp/jekyll-remote-theme-20230123-7-1e2b06p

**I ask you to help understand the deployment of this project and fix this problem.**

If it will be useful, a link to my test GitHub:

[My test GitHub](https://github.com/EVklo/evklo.github.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue is with your theme, the theme you want to use is not a "supported theme" so it must be added via `remote_theme`.

In your config you have your sites repo listed as the remote theme, but there is no theme info in your repo. Your post links the theme you want to use -- to use it the remote theme in the config should be as follows:

```yaml
remote_theme:  YoussefRaafatNasry/portfolYOU
```

See Github Pages [docs on themes](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll)

Comment: Milord, Thank you! Its works perfect!

And I realize that this might be out of scope for my original question, but could you please guide me on how I can create my own theme based on this one? Or maybe you know about the existence of guides on this topic.
I would like to slightly change the content of the pages, and this was the ultimate dream of mine.

Comment: Sure, you have two options that you could choose from based on your personal preferences. You can fork the theme you are currently using and update the `remote_theme` to point to your fork repository. Then make your edits there. Option 2 would be to put them theme right in your site repo and remove the `remote_theme` (and `theme`) tags from the config. Then you can edit them in place there.